# Fossil Gen 4 NFC Unsupported

Tags: kotlin, nfc, wear-os

I am having issues with implementing NFC capabilities in my Wear OS Fossil 4 smartwatch. First I tried to create a background service, which I understand, for now is not possible in Wear OS. So I moved towards enabling NFC in foreground, BUT sadly it's showing me the following error:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at android.nfc.NfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(NfcAdapter.java:1345)

If someone can give me a hand with solving this issue, it will be of great help (I bought the Wear OS device specifically to develop an NFC based project for the Smartwatch).
Thx

Comment: I'm afraid that Wear OS supports HCE only, no NFC tag reading or p2p. That was the situation for the watches last year and I don't think it changed.

Comment: Ok, thx.  I will try to find a workaround. It's sad cause if we want to develop new software that take advantage of the tech and promote it by using the sensors, it's impossible to progress...

Comment: @YonyBmn were you able to figure it out? I've been trying to use NFC with a Galaxy Watch4 without any success. I keep getting the same error you were getting